# Haxe -- Embed files like in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, embedded-resource, haxe

In ActionScript, you can do something like this:

```
[Embed(source = "src/myfile.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
private var xml : Class;
```

and it will embed your file to be used in code. How can i do something similar in Haxe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haxe allows you to provide external resources info for embedding in hxml.

You may refer to the [doc](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-resources.html).

Answer (score 11):

Things have changed since the time the question was asked. With a modern version of haxe one can do:

```
@:bitmap("test.png") class TestBMD extends BitmapData {}
var bm = new Bitmap(new TestBMD(100,100));
```

Comment: Why for God sake should I enter width and height of the image? This is terrible practice! If I have a hundred of images I would waste tons of time finding their sizes and entering them as magical numbers.  I hope Haxe's developers will overthink this and make something similar to flash's [embed] tag, which was not perfect but at least not such a headache.

Comment: If you specify 0, 0 for the width and height it should be fine. When I tried it with anything other than 0 it seemed to ignore the values specified anyway.

Comment: And actually it's exactly the way it behaves in flash under the hood. swf container integrates with avm bytecode in this predefined way.

Answer (score 2):

If specifying width/height annoys you, and if you don't mind not using the `@:bitmap` metatag, you could do:

```
import openfl.Assets;
...
var bm = new Bitmap(Assets.getBitmapData("test.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is easy to use haxe to get. Add `-resource myfile.xml@myxml`. Then, in your code, to get the xml string, use `haxe.Resource.getString("myxml")`. You can then parse this string to xml.

Comment: So the `@myxml` portion is what identifies the file with an alias when used in the actual Haxe code (with Resource.getString) ?