# FlashDevelop -- Specify an HXML file?

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe

[[a continuation of this question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664148/haxe-embed-files-like-in-actionscript)

In order to embed resources in a SWF file, I have to add lines to my HXML file. However, since I'm using FlashDevelop, I don't know where to find that. Where should I put stuff I would ordinarily specify in my HXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the case of specifying resources, you can do this by specifying a command line argument (right click the project in the Project view, select Properties..., then click Compiler Options > Additional Compiler Options and add it there).

Answer (score 4):

There's more detailed help about the projects settings you need in the [*Haxe* wiki](http://old.haxe.org/com/ide/haxefd/haxe_flashdevelop4).

> You can use a custom `.hxml` file to build your project in FlashDevelop.
>   Go to *Project -> Properties...*. Choose *Custom Build* as compilation target. Go to the *Build* tab and insert the following line in the *Pre-Build Command Line* field (assuming you named your build configuration `compile.hxml` and placed it in the root of the project directory):
>
> ```
> $(CompilerPath)\haxe.exe $(ProjectDir)\compile.hxml
> ```

Comment: Also worth mentioning - If you have spaces in either your Haxe install path or Project path, wrap them up in double-quotes (individually), like this: **"$(CompilerPath)\haxe.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\compile.hxml"** . I was struggling for a good 45mins / 1hour to figure out why I kept getting "*Exception: The system cannot find the file specified*" in FlashDevelop's Output Panel. There you have it!